# Webhooks: file_get_contents is empty

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to learn how to use webhooks. I have a localhost environment with ngrok to get https link for my webhook callback url. But I'm having problems with receiving the webhook data. 
This is the code i'm using to get the webhook data:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$webhook = file_get_contents('php://input');
$webhook_array = json_decode($webhook, true);
var_dump($webhook_array);
http_response_code(200);

echo $webhook_array->Content->Topic;
if($webhook_array->Content->Action == "Update"){
  echo $event->data->object->id;
}

?>
```

Because I'm using ngrok i can see what is getting posted to my php file, it looks like this:

```
{
    "Content": {
        "Topic": "Items",
        "ClientId": "423de8c8-409e-46f2-8d57-dc7eab60b747",
        "Division": 2286072,
        "Action": "Update",
        "Key": "90197dc4-34ca-4627-af77-288ea5c3cdd6",
        "ExactOnlineEndpoint": "123412341234')",
        "EventCreatedOn": "2018-11-28T15:13:56.607"
    },
    "HashCode": "1234123412341234"
}
```

My php code response is this:

```
NULL
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'Content' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\exact\webhooks.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'Topic' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\exact\webhooks.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'Content' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\exact\webhooks.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'Action' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\exact\webhooks.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
```

The NULL is from var_dump, and the trying to get property error's are there because $webhook_array is empty. So the main problem is that file_get_contents doesn't get the data from the post.
How would i troubleshoot this? Or what can I do to get the data using file_get_contents?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @jeroen So i need to delete the true from the json_decode because that makes it and array in stead of and object?

Comment: @FlubberBeer Yes - it's currently returning an associative array (so $webhook_array['Content] will work, $webhook_array->Content won't). Either change it to false or remove it (it defaults to false) or treat the json as an associative array